# Python cmd module multilevel tab complete (from two or more lists)

Tags: python

My current version (cleaned for this example) of CLI works pretty well with two levels of tab completion. I'm running out of ideas on how to add competition from 2nd list of things to choose from.

Here my current version:

```
from cmd import Cmd

settings = ['first','second','third']
parameters = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie']

class Prompt(Cmd):

    def __init__(self):
        Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.prompt = 'Command: '
        self.setting1 = ""
        self.setting2 = ""
        self.setting3 = ""

    def completenames(self, text, *ignored):
        # Modified tab complete to add extra space after command
        dotext = 'do_'+text
        return [a[3:]+' ' for a in self.get_names() if a.startswith(dotext)]

    def do_set(self, args):
        params = args.split()
        if len(params) == 0:
            print('Setting 1 = ' + self.setting1)
            print('Setting 2 = ' + self.setting2)
            print('Setting 3 = ' + self.setting3)
        else:
            if params[0] in settings and len(params) > 1:
                if params[0] == settings[0]:
                    self.setting1 = params[1]
                    print('Setting 1 = ' + self.setting1)
                elif params[0] == settings[1]:
                    self.setting2 = params[1]
                    print('Setting 2 = ' + self.setting2)
                elif params[0] == settings[2]:
                    self.setting3 = params[1]
                    print('Setting 3 = ' + self.setting3)
            else:
                print('Usage:')
                print('set <setting> <value>')
                print('type "set" for possible settings and their current value')

    def complete_set(self, text, line, start_index, end_index):
        if text:
            return [
                command + ' ' for command in settings
                if command.startswith(text)
            ]
        else:
            return settings

    def do_EOF(self, inp):
        print('\n')
        return True

Prompt().cmdloop()
```

With two levels, this works just fine:

```
Command: <tab>s<tab> fi<tab>
```

the result is: `set first`

What I want is to have the third option tab-completed from this parameter list. So it would look like this:

```
Command: <tab>s<tab> fi<tab> br<tab>
```

the result would naturally be: `set first bravo`

Comment: One way to do it would be to store a dictionary tree (dictionaries within dictionaries) of all possible options to choose from. The autocomplete function could run recursively: parse the first argument, look for it in the dictionary. Call the function recursively, this time on the first argument's dictionary and parsing the second argument, etc. This will give you a general solution, allowing for as many levels of auto completion as you want. It will also get rid of all the if/elses in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to my own problem:

```
    def complete_set(self, text, line, start_index, end_index):
    if len(line.split()) == 2:  # Only complete the parameter if setting is already provided
        return [
            command + ' ' for command in parameters
            if command.startswith(text)
        ]
    else:
        return [
            command + ' ' for command in settings
            if command.startswith(text)
        ]
```